# Blender Video Editing Image Sequence Caching not working

Tags: video-sequence-editor

If I add a still Image to the Video Sequencer and start playback, there is hardly more than 5 fps while playing. Even with activated proxies this problem still exists.

Further investigation showed me the cause:
Blender is reloading the image from disk (network share) for **every** frame.

How can I activate caching, so it does not need to reload the image over and over?
In the Proxy/Cache tab all boxes in "Cache Settings" are checked.

Blender Version is v2.82.7

Edit:

I compared my results with blender v2.7 and noticed that increasing the "Sequencer Cache Limit" in the "System"-Preferences solved my problem in that Version.

It seems blender v2.8 ignores this value and discards all caching.

Comment: Maybe this should be reported as a regression here: https://developer.blender.org/